# Enable and use Powershell remoting

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, powershell, remote-access

I have a Windows 10 Professional (Anniversary Update) machine `PC1` with user `user1` (Administrator) and a Windows 7 Professional machine `PC2` with user `user2` (Administrator). They both belong to a **workgroup** (not a domain) called `MYWORKGROUP` and they are in the same LAN, with private addresses (192.168.1.x).

Running Powershell as Administrator from `user1` in `PC1`, I followed [this guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wmi/2009/07/24/powershell-remoting-between-two-workgroup-machines/) as suggested in the comments and I also included `PC1` in the list of trusted hosts of `PC2` with

```
winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="PC1"}'
```

as suggested in the answer.

Then I logged in `PC2` as `user2` and ran from Powershell console

```
PS C:\>$cred = Get-Credentials
```

I gave my username as `PC1\User2` and my `PC1` password. Then I ran

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName "PC1" -Credential $cred
```

The error it gives is now:

```
PS C:\> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName "PC1" -Credential $cred
Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server PC1 failed with the following error message : Access is
denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName PC1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (PC1:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportExceptio
   n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

In such a scenario, what else should be done in order to make the Powershell console in `PC2` able to run remote commands in `PC1`?

Note that user `user2` exists in both `PC1` and `PC2` with (now) the same password; anyway, in `PC1` it is not Administrator. Maybe should it?

Comment: What error did you get when you tried to execute `Enter-PSSession PC1`?

Comment: @cascer1 I edited my question with the error message.

Comment: You may find some helpful info here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wmi/2009/07/24/powershell-remoting-between-two-workgroup-machines/

Comment: @root I followed the whole guide, but I can't still connect.

Comment: just because have same user name on 2 pcs, does not mean that they are the same user. They are still different users. Make a group on both machines call MyRemUser or other name y/all like. Add the other PC user to this group, and give this group the appropriate rights.

Comment: When done correctly, should see PC1\User2 or PC2\USer2 depending on which machine you are on. Without the leading machine name, it is assumed to be the current or local machine. User2 without the lead indicates it is the current local PC

Comment: @bvaughn Ok! I didn't create a group, but I tried to log in (from `PC2`) as `PC1\User2`. `User2` already exists on `PC1`. And it still gives me the same error. Is it because `User2` is not an Administrator on `PC1`?

Comment: Possible,  need to set rights at either the user level or the group level

Answer (score 1):

You should add your `PC2` to the `TrustedHosts` on `PC1` by running this on `PC1`:

```
winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="PC2"}'
```

Comment: I've done it, thank you, but the connection still gives error.

Comment: Is it the same error? Access denied?

Comment: Yes, access denied. The problem was about the rights of `user2` on `PC1` (he was not Administrator), as said in the comments above.